# How can I get sudo back to work? Any sudo results in "sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts"

Tags: sudo, password

I had problems with some ssh connection and finally ended up with disenabling my `sudo` completely. Any `sudo` command results in

```
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
```

Surprisingly, I am never actually asked to enter a password. Maybe this is already a problem.

I would appreciate any help

Comment: *"disenabling my sudo completely"* how, exactly?

Comment: What did you actually do? Which commands did you run? Which config files did you edit?

Comment: I am not completely sure, which command caused that sudo does not work anymore. I tried to changed authorized keys, .ssh/config and other ssh-related  files.

Comment: Could it be that it has something to do with the command cat /etc/pam.d/sudo ?

Comment: Login to root `su root` then type `passwd username`. You will be able to change the password. Maybe you edited `passwd` file by mistake

Comment: 'su root' gives 'su: Authentication failure'

Comment: I guess this is what happens when you " disenabling my sudo completely" . The first step is going to be to obtain root access. If you can not sudo or su from your user, can you ssh in as root ? If not you are going to need to boot to recovery mode. Do you have physical access to the server ?

Comment: @Panther, I now booted to recovery mode. Could you please help me how to proceed?

Comment: can you post the output of `id your_username` to start with and make sure your user is in /etc/sudoers either by name or group.

Comment: uid=1001(ac) gid=1002(ac) groups=1002(ac), 0(root), 4(adm), 20(dialout), 21(fax), 24(cdrom), 25(floppy), 26(tape), 27(sudo), 30(dip), 44(video), 46(plugdev), 105(fuse), 110(lpadim), 123(sambashare)

Comment: post `grep sudo /etc/sudoers`

Comment: I guess this line is of importance
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Comment: It should be working. `su your_user` and try sudo , post any errors. May need to look at permissions of sudo , but that usually give a different error.

Comment: su my_user  gives  su: Authentification failure
I am still in the recovery mode. Is this correct?

Comment: and you are sure you are using the correct password for your user account? Reset your user password with `passwd uer_name` and run `faillog -u your_user -r` , then try `su your_user` and sudo from your account again

Comment: This does not work. When I did passwd my_username , I was asked to enter a new password (2 times) but then it said passwd: Authentication token manipulation error   passwd: wassword unchanged.     By the way, many thanks for your efforts!

Comment: did you remount in rw ? otherwise your file system is ro. `mount -o remount,rw /` and try again . If that fails, will have to wait , have plans for the day.

Comment: the password change was now successful. But faillog -u my_username -r        results in faillog: Cannot open /var/log/faillog: Read-only file system

Comment: try su and sudo again. check to see if outer file systems are mounted ro, `mount | grep ro` and remount them also. re run faillog .....

Comment: `su my_username` gives still `su: Authentication failure`;  
`mount -ro remount,rw /`  results in `mount: /dev/sda1 already mounted or / busy`    `mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda1 is already mounted on /` ;   and `mount | grep ro` gives `/dev/sda1 on / type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)`   `         check the /proc/mounts file.`